# C++ namespace function definition only has static keyword

Tags: c++, static

I understand that a static namespace function may be declared static, and the static keyword omitted from the definition of the function. What I have is the opposite, e.g.:

```
// in foo.h
namespace Foo
{
    void bar();
}

// in foo.cpp
static void Foo::bar()
{
}
```

Does the static keyword have any effect here, or is it simply ignored? It compiles either way, and the functions are available to other translation units.

Comment: On my system, I get `error: static declaration of 'bar' follows non-static declaration`

Comment: What compiler and version did you use to compile that code?

Comment: `static` in this context means: this symbol is visible only in current translation unit. So if it compiles, it will lead to linking issue when symbol is used in different translation unit.

Comment: clang, gcc and MSVC all reject this code: https://godbolt.org/z/nY4c7fsqs. The only way it might compile is if `foo.h` isn't included in `foo.cpp`

Comment: I'm using armcc

Comment: @stuwilmur The program is not valid. See the explanation given [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73069129/12002570)

Comment: Thanks: what puzzles me is that armcc doesn't seem to complain...

Comment: After some digging in the armcc documentation I found this: "The compiler suppresses errors about linkage disagreements, where functions are implicitly declared as extern and later re-declared as static, unless the --strict option is used"

Answer (score 2):

The given program is ill-formed as can be seen from [dcl.stc](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.stc#6) which states:

> The linkages implied by successive declarations for a given entity shall agree. That is, within a given scope, each declaration declaring the same variable name or the same overloading of a function name shall imply the same linkage.

(end quote)

Now, lets apply this to your example.

```
// in foo.h
namespace Foo
{
    void bar(); //#1 external linkage
}

// in foo.cpp
static void Foo::bar()  //#2 tries to give Foo::bar internal linkage 
{
}
```

In the above code, the first declaration `#1` of `bar` gives it **external linkage** while when implementing it in the source file(foo.cpp) in `#2`, you're trying to give it **internal linkage**. And so according to the above quoted statement, the given example is not valid.